# Нужно ли ставить запятые в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Однажды(,) в ее присутствии(,) она случайно разбила тарелку.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Джамиля вы поняли? В следующих вопросах вы сначала предлагаете свои варианты ответов с объяснением, только так вы будете чему-то учиться, а не копировать готовые ответы.

Comment: Только так я буду учиться? Нет, я и так все понимаю, мне же дают объяснение.  А что измениться, если я предложу еще и свои варианты тем, кто и так знает ответ на мой вопрос? Он же не нуждается в них. А свои возможные ответы я и так знаю, нет смысла предлагать их.

Comment: @Джамиля Вы стали принимать ответы галочкой, но почему-то не благодарите отвечающих стрелочкой вверх (они ведь старались помочь, потратили свое время и дали информацию для Вас и других пользователей).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы правильно расставить запятые, надо провести **разбор предложения**.
Чтобы правильно провести разбор предложения, надо поставить вопросы от одних слов к другим.

Когда? **Однажды** // обстоятельство времени.

При каких обстоятельствах? **В её присутствии** // обстоятельственный причинный оборот. Обычно не обособляют.

(Кто? Что сделала? Что?) **она разбила тарелку** // подлежащее, сказуемое, дополнение.

Каким образом? **случайно** // обстоятельство стечения/причины.

Таким образом, перед нами **простое** предложение с кучей обстоятельств. Их можно не обособлять.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic